How to use SparkListener outside sparkContext
My case is looking like:
I have created a mini Spark lib.
This lib instances are using by another developers inside their spark apps and I want to calculate my lib performance, hence, create "listener" for tasks/ stages and jobs performance benchmarks.
I have read about SparkListenerEvent but in this case, unfortunately, I need to config SparkContext. Spark context (like and Spark session config is outside of my control). Maybe I'm not right about SparkListenerEvent ? Or someone has faced with the same cases and know decision.
Thanks.

We are using Spark 2.4.1+

